# What does a 'shadow walker' look like to an outside observer?

Tags: chronicles-of-amber

In the Chronicles of Amber, they explain 'shadow walking' fairly well. The pattern casts shadows from Amber to the Courts of Chaos, and every possible combination of events and laws of physics are possible in one shadow or another.

They don't however explain how a spectator would **observe** shadow walking. Would they see a ghostly apparition fade in/out/through the world or would they see someone just pop out of nowhere? Or would they see something else entirely?

Comment: About the only thing I remember that could answer this is Corwin speculating on if the nurse would see a rainbow afterimage of him when he trumped out.  I'm not sure we ever see it from a non shadow-walker perspective.  "I wondered how she would report this one-and if she would mention my prismatic afterimage as I trumped out." and "I bowed and blew her a kiss as I stepped forward into Amber, leaving her to clutch at rainbows as I caught hold of Random's shoulder and staggered."  That said, that's trumping out; it's suggested that even a normal can follow a shadow walker (closely) thru shadows

Answer (score 6):

Based on my multiple readings of the ten books (not counting the Betancourt novels), if an Amberite, Chaosite, or other initiate of some shadow of the Pattern or Logrus were to walk through my field of vision, I'd see nothing out of the ordinary.  A stranger would enter my field of view (almost certainly coming into sight from behind an obscuring object), continue walking, riding, running, or driving, and pass out of my vision, once again becoming obscured by something in the vicinity.

Unless I were also a Pattern or Logrus user, or a sensitive (rare, but present in most Shadows), I'd detect nothing out of the ordinary unless I specifically followed the Shadow Walker.  If I *did* specifically, intentionally follow (say, because I'm a child pretending to be a Private Investigator), there's a chance I might be drawn through Shadow along with the Walker, at least for a time, and wind up very, very confused, left in a world that is quite noticeably not my own without any explanation of how that had occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget the tecys, who pursued random closely through shadow. They entered our shadow in bathroom stalls, unseen!